# c# change equation every loop run

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm creating a pi calculator but i bumped into a problem, this is the code:

```cs
for (;;) {
pi = (4*(1/5 /*here would go - or + */ (1/(n * Pow(5, n))) ) ) - n;
n++;

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + pi);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Loop runs: " + loopRuns);
loopRuns += 1;
if (n == iterations)
  {
    Done(0);
    break;
  }
}
```

i need a way to make t so that every run of the loop, it varies - and +

any help appreciated.

Comment: like - + - + - + - + ... no condition just in sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to have a variable outside the loop:

```
int modifier = 1; // Or -1, depending on how you want to start
```

Then inside the loop:

```
pi = (4*(1/5 + (1/(n * Pow(5, n))) * modifier ) ) - n;
modifier *= -1;
```

Comment: Even simpler line 2, without a multiplication: `modifier = 0-modifier;`.  This will run faster.

Comment: Or, seeing that the sample is broken (loopRuns is incremented, but 'n' is used to break at some point): Change the code to use a real for loop from 0 .. iterations and change the modifier based on i % 2.
But I'd agree that you offer the solution here.

Comment: @codenoir While that is true, the performance difference between basic addition and multiplication in this case is essentially nil.

Comment: The performance is dependent on the number of iterations.  Given the context (computing pi) the number could be quite high.

Comment: @BenjaminPodszun That's the other approach I considered, but it would involve some kind of check (either by `if` or a ternary operator), so I opted for the solution that dealt only with simple arithmetic.

Comment: @codenoir The program will be far more hindered by the increasing computation requirements of `Pow` than the amount of time a single multiplication will ever take.

Comment: @codenoir A preliminary benchmark has me having to use `ElapsedTicks` rather than `ElapsedMilliseconds` because the time is so insignificant of arithmetic anyway, and even then I have to run the subtraction/multiplication at least a million times before the time difference even becomes remotely noticeable. Even then, I cannot trust the results of this test because we are talking about time differences so infinitesimal that I doubt it's even possible to reliably test for without highly specialized hardware.

Comment: @codenoir So like I said before, other places in his algorithm will be far greater concerns for performance gains than whether or not a single arithmetic operation uses multiplication or subtraction.